# Delete entities data with entity name

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

Im using the entityManager and i want to delete the data from specific entity with 
the entity name how can i do that .
I have tried to use entitymanager.removeAll() without success,there is different way to provide
the entityname and delete all the data inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("delete from entity").executeUpdate();
```

replacing "entity" with the name of your entity. It should work. But if you have cascading options with that entity, they won't be applied, and you'll have to apply them manually.

Another solution is to select all the rows and to delete each entity contained in the returned list in a loop, using the `remove(entity)` method of the entity manager.

Comment: The entity is refer to the entity name or the entity instance?I think that i should provide the entity instance...

Comment: It's the entity name, default is the simple class name.

Comment: You must take the class name without packages.